# Get all Parameter Values from a form with Similar Name but different Values in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have an HTML form which I will be using to update the Rates for all the Products in a Particular Category with the help of ProductID and also need to mention whether that product is available online or NO using a Radio Button.

```
<form>
        <%
            for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){%>
            Product ID <label><%=i%></label><br/>
            Product Name <input type="text" name="ValueA" value="<%=i%>"/><br/><br/>
            Product Available Online YES/NO<br/><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="RadioA" value="Yes" checked/> Yes
            <input type="radio" name="RadioA" value="No"/> No<br/><br/>
            -----------------------------------------------------------------<br/>
            <%}
        %>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

I want to know how do I get these input values in my JSP page after the form is submitted.

Comment: inputs name should also be changed to `ValueA<%=i%>` and for the radio `RadioA<%=i%>` ... otherwise you will "override" all ten occurrences. And the radio change will change all, if same name used.

Comment: You will find the values using request.getParameter("ValueA1") and request.getParameter("RadioA1") etc...

Comment: If no values in request use initial values, otherwise put the request.getParameter values in the value param in your form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am able to get the ValueA Input data using request.getParameterValues("ValueA") as request.getParameterValues retreives all the data of ValueA input and stores it in an Array and I am easily able to access all the data for ValueA. But I am not able to do the same for the Radio Buttons as the all the Radio Buttons cant have the same name and even if I add numbers in front of RadioA[1] then how do I get all the Values for RadioA like how I am getting for ValueA using request.getParameterValues.

Comment: You will need to set up a loop to read the radiobutton from 1 to 10. i.e. `getParameter("RadioA"+i)` ... if you dont know how long the loop will be, you can set a hidden field that send the number of radio buttons. But for your code it is 10. But upon change you can have it more flexible, instead of changing on lots of places you can have a hidden input field.

Comment: Sounds great to me. Just want to know one more thing is there a way from which we can skip this hidden value and loop part and use some other method to get Radio Values which will have the Name as RadioA[1], RadioA[2], etc...

Comment: You will need to do the getParameter for each radiobutton. Dont forget to check if null... This is easiest way, otherwise you might need to use other form types, muliparts, but this might do other problems in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your form action ? method ? if you wanted to get the values from your jsp page after the form is submitted you can use request.getparameter();

```
String name         = request.getParameter("ValueA");
String radio_value  = request.getParameter("RadioA");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am able to get the ValueA Input data using request.getParameterValues("ValueA") as request.getParameterValues retreives all the data of ValueA input and stores it in an Array and I am easily able to access all the data for ValueA. But I am not able to do the same for the Radio Buttons as the all the Radio Buttons cant have the same name and even if I add numbers in front of RadioA[1] then how do I get all the Values for RadioA like how I am getting for ValueA using request.getParameterValues.

Comment: Form action and method will be default, it is not a must. But though good coding practice.